# Technician Class HF Privileges in the USA

Tags: united-states, hf, legal, license

What are the current privileges below 30 MHz for holders in the United States of a Technician class license?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There's some CW on 80, 40, and 15 meters, and some RTTY and SSB on 10. Limited to 200W in all cases. Here's a [chart](http://www.arrl.org/files/file/Regulatory/Band%20Chart/Hambands_color.pdf).

Answer (score 0):

I refer you to the ARRL's bands PDF. http://www.arrl.org/files/file/Regulatory/Band%20Chart/Hambands_color.pdf

Anything marked with a 'T' is Technician.

Comment: Technically, that's not a band plan; that's a chart of the legal uses as specified by the FCC. A band plan is "a voluntary division of a band to avoid interference between incompatible modes". The ARRL also publishes a [band plan](http://www.arrl.org/band-plan) for the amateur frequencies.